# scraping 50 webpages each containing 10 webpage links

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook, iteration

i neeed to scrape 50 main webpages each webpage containing 10 article links. Date and authors are scrape from main page and verticals and description are scraped visiting each url link  so after scraping 10 links at first main webpage i need to click for the next page and the cycle continues to 50 pages .Please help me, here is my code.

```
#Importing essential libraries required for scraping articles.
    import pandas as pd
    import selenium
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait       
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By       
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
    
    
    driver=webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Scp\Desktop\fliprobo\chromedriver.exe")
    
    Dates=[]
    Authors=[]
    Verticals=[]
    Headlines=[]
    Descriptions=[]
    Hrefs=[]
    
    
    driver.get("https://www.ebmnews.com/2020/page/948/")
    start=948
    end=997
    for page in range(start,end+1):
authors=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//i[@class="post-author author"]')
    for i in authors:
        Authors.append(i.text)
    dates=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//time[@class="post-published updated"]')
    for i in dates:
        Dates.append(i.text)       
    urls=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="post-url post-title"]')
        urls=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="post-url post-title"]')
        for i in urls:
        driver.get(i.get_attribute('href'))
        headlines=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="post-99531"]/div[1]/h1/span')
            for i in headlines:
                Headlines.append(i.text)
            desc=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="post-99531"]/div[2]/p/span')
            for i in desc:
                Descriptions.append(i.text)
            verticals=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="post-99531"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/span/a')
            for i in verticals:
                Verticals.append(i.text)
            driver.back()
        try:
            element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[text()=" Older Posts"]')
            webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element ).click(element ).perform()
        except StaleElementReferenceException as e:
            old_post_btn=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[text()=" Older Posts"]')
            old_post_btn.click()
```

Comment: What problem are you having with the code above?

Comment: I am  able to get data(author & dates & links of articles urls) from 50 main webpages which contains 10 links to article urls, but i also need to get data(full description) from those 10 articles which i am not able to get through this code

Comment: Why are you using selenium for this? The content that you wish to grab from there seem to be static which requests module can handle.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Comment: Also check [can someone help me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: my code lets me scrape data from main webpage i.e 948 and then opens the first article, scrape data and comes back to main webpage but then either it stops there by state element reference or goes to next main webpage i.e 949 (that means it doesnt scrope rest of the 9 webpage url which is my problem)  sorry  i am new to this field and not able to clear my question

Comment: In the start, I have to go to page no.948  that contains 10 articles urls of news. DATE, AUTHOR & HEADINGS of aticles are to be scraped from page number 948 while  DESCRIPTION & VERTICAL of articles are to be scraped by opening webpage of each article through urls of articles. I have to do it for next 50 pages 948-997.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, the following should serve the purpose in the right way. I used requests module instead of selenium to make it robust.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.ebmnews.com/2020/page/{}/'

current_page = 948

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36'
    
    while current_page!=998: #highest page to traverse
        r = s.get(url.format(current_page))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
        for item in soup.select('article.listing-item'):
            try:
                post_author = item.select_one("i.post-author").get_text(strip=True)
            except AttributeError: post_author = ""
            try:
                post_date = item.select_one("span.time > time").get_text(strip=True)
            except AttributeError: post_date = ""
            inner_link = item.select_one("h2.title > a").get("href")

            res = s.get(inner_link)
            sauce = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
            title = sauce.select_one("span[itemprop='headline']").get_text(strip=True)
            desc = ' '.join([item.get_text(strip=True) for item in sauce.select(".entry-content > p")])
            print(post_author,post_date,title,desc)

        current_page+=1
```

Answer (score -2):

You should use scrapy selenium slower than scrapy and complex.

Comment: Thanks brother but i am a novice and currently i am learning on beatifulsoup and selenium so need to finish this task through it only

Comment: Do specify if it's a comment, this reply is opinionated and is not an answer to the question